# Find the range of $|a|$ in $ \sec \theta+\csc \theta=a,$ where $\theta \in (0,2\pi)-\{\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\} $

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the range of $|a|$  in $ \sec \theta+\csc \theta=a,$ where  $\theta \in (0,2\pi)-\{\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\} $ if the equation has
>
> 1) four real roots
>
> 2) two real roots
>
> 3) no real roots

I have tried converting everything to $\sin$ and using double angle formula and then find range , I have tried squaring both the sides. I was thinking about graphs but how am I suppose to know graph such complex functions?

I am a high school student.

Comment: A graph (using a graphing calculator) would be extremely useful. You would see that there is always either four, three, or two solutions. Of course, we would then try to prove these results.

Comment: @Lozenges answer of a) is greater than equal to $2\sqrt 2 $. B) less than $2\sqrt 2 $. C) is none.

Comment: OK. For $a=2 \sqrt{2}$ we have three roots with one double root $\theta =\pi /4$ . So counting multiplicity we get a total of four roots. The other roots are $\theta =11\pi /12$ and $\theta =19\pi /12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^2=\sec^2t+\csc^2t+2\sec t\csc t=(2\csc2t+1)^2-1$$

Now if $\csc2t>0,2\csc2t+1\ge3,a^2\ge9-1\implies|a|\ge2\sqrt2$

If $\csc2t<0, 2\csc2t+1\le-1,a^2\ge0$ which holds true for all real $a$

So, all real values of $a$ admit solutions

If $\csc2t=-1,a^2=1;$

$2t=2n\pi-\dfrac\pi2\iff t=?$ so, two solutions in $(0<t<2\pi)$

Similarly for $\csc2t=1$

If $\csc2t>1$

$\implies2t$ lies in the first two quadrants and $a^2>8,$

there will be four solutions in $0<2t<4\pi$

What if $\csc2t<1?$

Comment: @Swarnim, not clear what is your confusion

Answer (score 0):

I will do the last case. That is, find bounds on $a$ such that the resulting equation has no roots.

The equation yields $$\sin\theta+\cos\theta=a\sin(2\theta)\implies 2\sqrt 2\cos\left(\theta-\frac π4\right)=a\sin(2\theta).$$

Thus if you take $|a|\ne 2\sqrt 2$ there would definitely not be a solution. You can check the case when $|a| = 2\sqrt 2$ separately to see if there are solutions given the other conditions of the problem. This should tell you either that there are no solutions for all $|a|,$ or on the contrary just for $|a|\ne 2\sqrt 2,$ definitively settling the third part.

Comment: Thus if you take $|a|\ne 2\sqrt 2$ there would definitely not be a solution. Can you please explain? Range of lest hand side would be -2$\sqrt2 $ to $+2\sqrt 2 $ and rhs be -a to a if there is and intersection then there will be roots.

Comment: @swarnim The third part asks for values of $a$ for which no real solution exists. No real solution exists if $\text{LHS}\ne\text{RHS}.$ That will happen provided $|a|\ne 2\sqrt 2.$ To find out whether that is also necessary to guarantee no solution, you'd have to consider the other constraint on $\theta$ separately, but that should be easy since $\theta$ is in a bounded range.

Comment: I just cheked the answer for that problem, it turns out to be a = {$\phi $} or null which means for any value of a there is be some solutions.

Comment: @swarnim Are you sure you wrote exactly what you saw, because the notation $a=\{\phi\}$ is nonsense. The symbol $a$ is a number, and the other is a set containing exactly one set, namely the empty set. As for the claim that all values of $a$ yield a solution; that's easily dismissed as incorrect. Take $a=4\sqrt2,$ for example. Then I claim that no *real* solution can exist. It follows with greater force that there can be no $\theta$ in the permitted range which solves the equation for $a=4\sqrt2.$ Try it.

Comment: the value of the function at $\frac{5\pi }{12}$ equals $2 \sqrt{6}$